# Difference between word-wrap: break-word and word-break: break-word

Tags: html, css, word-wrap, word-break

I needed to fix some CSS somewhere because my text wasn't wrapping around and was instead going on indefinitely if it was an extremely long word.

Like in most cases, I tried `word-wrap: break-word;` in my CSS file and it did not work.

Then, to my surprise, and by the suggestion of Google Chrome Developer Tools, I tried `word-break: break-word;` and it fixed my problem. I was shocked by this so I've been googling to know the difference between these two but I have seen nothing on the subject.

Further, I don't think `word-break: break-word;` is documented behavior seeing as how [W3](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp) has no mention of it. I tested it on Safari and Chrome, and it works perfectly on both, but I'm hesitant to use `word-break: break-word;` because I see no mention of it anywhere.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update**

If you plan on breaking words and want to hyphenate as well, try the following:

```
.hyphenate {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

This worked even in Chrome ... sort of ... sans hyphens. Anyways a detailed explanation is in this [article](https://justmarkup.com/log/2015/07/dealing-with-long-words-in-css/).

---

`word-break:break-word` is not documented and only master developers know this ultra secret technique like the *Quivering Palm of Death*.

Actually it's an obscure `-webkit-` property that works like `word-wrap: break-word` but it's also used on dynamic lengths as well.

**[Kenneth.io - Word Wrapping Hypernation Using CSS](https://kenneth.io/blog/2012/03/04/word-wrapping-hypernation-using-css/)**

**[CSS-Tricks - word-break](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/word-break/)**

From [**CaniUse**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=word-break):

> Chrome, Safari and other WebKit/Blink browsers also support the unofficial `break-word` value which is treated like `word-wrap: break-word`.

Comment: I see. I guess the reason it works for me is because "it's also used on dynamic lengths as well". I'll need to rectify that somehow so that I can instead use `word-wrap: break-word;` I'd rather not rely on something that isn't officially documented/supported across all relevant browsers.

Comment: If you are breaking words, I assume you'll want to hyphenate them as well. See the update in my post.