# Css - understanding "word-wrap: break-word;"

Tags: html, css

I have a small problem with css style. I'm trying to do breakline if the text in the span is too long. I expect that before the third SPAN perform a line break. But something goes wrong. Please for assistance.

Code:

```
<span id="j_id0:j_id12" class="sp">Abcd abcdabcd2
   <span style="border-style: dotted; word-wrap: break-word; width: 80px;" 
   class="absoluteLeft">Add you viewing ten equally believe put</span>
</span>
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e50dj9fa/3/)

Comment: First you don't have absoluteLeft class, second what is the main issue?

Comment: @Adamo `word-wrap: break-word;` will only work with elements that have specific widths - therefore you cannot set it on an `inline` element.  In your code provided, your span is inline, which means the width will be ignored and so word wrap will not work.  Either make your span a `block`, or `inline-block` element

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/8k08nyr0/1/

Comment: @zer00ne I must have something like that: https://jsfiddle.net/e50dj9fa/3/

Comment: @zer00ne check his updated fiddle plz

Comment: This is what I see https://jsfiddle.net/e50dj9fa/3/

Comment: Yea, ant it's a issue. I expect that if I have word-wrap the span with value abcdabcd3 will automatic break line and add empty line.

Comment: inline elements make lines unbreakable, it's their nature.

Comment: Understand, so I must change that span to block ?

Comment: Yes or inline-block is better since you want to line it up with that other span to it's left. Remove that `position: absolute` and `left:175px` as well. And give this a read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35251345/2813224 I think you need to do something else.

Comment: @zer00ne We did not understand well. I mean that I would get such an effect as now: https://jsfiddle.net/e50dj9fa/4/  but without the use of breaklines in Abcd abcdabcd3. I would like to be able to get through pure css, 
because they do not know how the text will be a long and how much breaklines 
I have to insert

Comment: If you have a long word, and your container's width (and possibly height) is not an absolute value (such as px), then the hopes of breaking (or hyphenating) it are futile. I suggest a different route…like…ellipsis…and…the…use…of…`display:table`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Span is inline element, so it won't break word. If you need to break word the element should be a block (ex. div) or should be displayed as such (then you need to add display:block to your span's css).

EDIT
 I don't know why you need a class "absoluteLeft". I'd remove that. And then I'd add in a css:

```
span span {
   display:inline-block;
}
```

And, of course, you have to remove from dotted span a style display:block;

Does that resolve your problem?

Comment: Please read full question with issue then try to give answer with desired output. Thankx

Comment: I wan't something like that https://jsfiddle.net/e50dj9fa/4/ but without breaklines

Comment: I don't think you used my tip. You still have absolute positioning and span's child isn't displayed as inline-block. Look: https://jsfiddle.net/e50dj9fa/7/

Answer (score 0):

Put display:block; to span

```
<span id="j_id0:j_id12" class="sp">Abcd abcdabcd2
       <span style="border-style: dotted; word-wrap: break-word; width: 80px;display:block;" 
       class="absoluteLeft">Add you viewing ten equally believe put</span>
    </span>
```

Comment: anyone can please tell me about giving downrate of this answer, no comment given for this ?