# Matching table height for nested HTML tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I am trying to nest tables within a table row, while maintaining the appearance of a single table, as shown in the example below (a table with a single row with a data value and two nested tables, one 2x2 and the other 3x3) :

[image]

This is just an example; the actual table has significantly more rows and columns. I want to use tables because of the natural reflowing of column widths and row heights to fit the table data without having to worry about the container size (i.e. table width = 100%).

The problem I am having is that the tallest table sets the row height, but the other tables don't expand to fill that height, so the internal borders don't stretch from top to bottom as shown in the result of this snippet:

```css
.display {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
.display, .display td, .display th {
 border: 1px solid black;
}
.subtable {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
.subtable td {
 border-top: 0;
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 border-left: 0;
 border-right: 1px solid black;
}
.subtable tr td:last-of-type {
 border-top: 0;
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 border-left: 0;
  border-right: 0;
}
.subtable tr:last-of-type td {
 border-top: 0;
 border-bottom: 0;
 border-left: 0;
 border-right: 1px solid black;
}
.subtable tr:last-of-type td:last-of-type {
 border: 0;
}
td {
 padding: 5px;
}
td.d-subtable {
 padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="display" cellpadding="0">
 <tr><th>Customer</th><th>Items</th><th>Payments</th></tr>
 <tr><td>Customer Name</td>
  <td class="d-subtable"><table class="subtable" cellpadding="0"><tr><td>Item1</td><td>5</td><td>$400.00</td></tr><tr><td>Item2</td><td>10</td><td>$200.00</td></tr><tr><td>Item3</td><td>2</td><td>$500.00</td></tr></table></td>
  <td class="d-subtable"><table class="subtable" cellpadding="0"><tr><td>12 Sep 2018</td><td>$3,000.00</td></tr><tr><td>18 Sep 2018</td><td>$2,000.00</td></tr></table></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Now I know I can resolve this problem using rowspan (and that is how I am currently solving the problem) but that requires deciding in advance which rows to line up and that can lead to issues such as that generated by the below snippet, where it would clearly be better if I'd applied `rowspan="2"` to the first row (instead of the last row) of the table with 2 rows:

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="5">
 <tr><td rowspan="3">x</td>
  <td>problem when you have some really long text in the first row</td><td>p</td><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr><tr><td rowspan="2">z</td><td rowspan="2">q</td><td>d</td><td>e</td><td>f</td></tr><tr><td>g</td><td>some other really long text</td><td>i</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

I would prefer the above table to look like this:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve what I want using HTML/CSS? There are a lot of rows in the table so I'd prefer the browser sort it out before rendering. However if it's not possible I'm open to a Javascript/JQuery solution.

**Update**

Although I did find a workable solution at the time (see my posted answer) I have since encountered some situations where setting the widths of the columns in advance (even as percentages) was difficult owing to not being able to anticipate all the possible data to be displayed. So I'm hoping to find an answer that doesn't rely on doing that.

Since I didn't make it as clear as I should have, I have multiple rows in which I want to nest tables, keeping the heights matched as well as the column widths. For example, for two rows, I would like to be able to create a layout like this:

[image]

Where with raw table HTML the result looks like this:

[image]

```css
  .display {
   border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  .display, .display td, .display th {
   border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .subtable {
   border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  .subtable td {
   border-top: 0;
   border-bottom: 1px solid black;
   border-left: 0;
   border-right: 1px solid black;
  }
  .subtable tr td:last-of-type {
   border-top: 0;
   border-bottom: 1px solid black;
   border-left: 0;
   border-right: 0;
  }
  .subtable tr:last-of-type td {
   border-top: 0;
   border-bottom: 0;
   border-left: 0;
   border-right: 1px solid black;
  }
  .subtable tr:last-of-type td:last-of-type {
   border: 0;
  }
  td {
   padding: 5px;
  }
  td.d-subtable {
   padding: 0;
  }
```

```html
<table class="display" cellpadding="0">
 <tr><th>Customer</th><th>Items</th><th>Payments</th></tr>
 <tr><td>Customer 1</td>
  <td class="d-subtable"><table class="subtable" cellpadding="0"><tr><td>Item1</td><td>5</td><td>$400.00</td></tr><tr><td>Item2</td><td>100</td><td>$20.00</td></tr><tr><td>Item3</td><td>2</td><td>$500.00</td></tr></table></td>
  <td class="d-subtable"><table class="subtable" cellpadding="0"><tr><td>12 Sep 2018</td><td>$3,000.00</td></tr><tr><td>18 Sep 2018</td><td>$2,000.00</td></tr></table></td>
 </tr>
 <tr><td>Customer 304</td>
  <td class="d-subtable"><table class="subtable" cellpadding="0"><tr><td>Item4</td><td>5</td><td>$6.00</td></tr></table></td>
  <td class="d-subtable"><table class="subtable" cellpadding="0"><tr><td>20 Sep 2018</td><td>$4.00</td></tr><tr><td>27 Sep 2018</td><td>$26.00</td></tr></table></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your formatting doesn't appear to show a table of data. Instead it appears that you just want to visualize data in some sort of custom grid. I wouldn't recommend using `<table>` to attempt to solve this problem if it's not semantically a table.

Comment: @zzzzBov I do have a table of data. There are many more columns and rows than I have shown in my example; I was just trying to create a minimal example that demonstrated the issue I have. I want to use a table because of its ability to reflow column widths and row heights to fit data to the container.

Comment: i think a better solution for your case would be to use CSS Grid instead of tables. It will give you much more control.

Comment: Wanted to let you know I have a newly updated question based on your input, which I'm grateful for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a JavaScript solution that sets both the row heights and column widths automatically (does not require specifying column widths), and supports resizing.

The complete solution/demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/ez0jqc1L/

The one caveat is this requires that you wrap the content of all `<td>` cells with `<div class="content"></div>` (see the jsfiddle for an example).

First, we fix the subtable heights:

```
let tbody = /* the tbody of the <table> containing subtables we are fixing */;
for(let r = 0; r < tbody.children.length; r++) {
    let row = tbody.children[r];
    let subtables = row.querySelectorAll('.subtable');
    let maxHeight = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < subtables.length; i++) {
        maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, subtables[i].clientHeight);
    }
    for(let i = 0; i < subtables.length; i++) {
        subtables[i].style.height = maxHeight + 'px';
    }
}
```

Then, we iterate over all subtable columns to compute the max width for each set of vertically adjacent cells (we store this into the `maxColWidths` array, each index of the array corresponds to the set of vertically adjacent cells):

```
let forEachSubtableColumn = function(f) {
    for(let r = 0; r < tbody.children.length; r++) {
        let row = tbody.children[r];
        let subtables = row.querySelectorAll('.subtable');
        let c = 0;
        for(let i = 0; i < subtables.length; i++) {
            let subtable = subtables[i];
            if(subtable.children.length === 0 || subtable.children[0].children.length === 0) {
                continue;
            }
            let stbody = subtable.children[0];
            for(let j = 0; j < stbody.children.length; j++) {
                let srow = stbody.children[j];
                for(let k = 0; k < srow.children.length; k++) {
                    let td = srow.children[k];
                    f(c + k, td);
                }
            }
            c += stbody.children[0].children.length;
        }
    }
};
let maxColWidths = []; 
forEachSubtableColumn(function(c, td) {
    if(c >= maxColWidths.length) {
        maxColWidths.push(td.children[0].clientWidth);
    } else {
        maxColWidths[c] = Math.max(td.children[0].clientWidth, maxColWidths[c]);
    }
});
```

Finally, we set the column widths. This is where the `<div class="content">` wrapping is required, because setting the width of a `<td>` does not guarantee the browser will make it that exact width, but I can have this guarantee with an element having `display: inline-block`.

```
forEachSubtableColumn(function(c, td) {
    td.children[0].style.width = maxColWidths[c] + 'px';
});
```

For resizing support we clear all the forced widths and heights so we can recompute them afterwards:

```
onresize = function() {
    let tables = document.querySelectorAll('.subtable');
    for(let i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
        let table = tables[i];
        table.style.removeProperty('height');
    }
    let tds = document.querySelectorAll('.subtable td');
    for(let i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
        let td = tds[i];
        td.children[0].style.removeProperty('width');
    }
    updateTables();
};
```

**EDIT:** Corrected the `onresize` code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This looks interesting. In your fiddle a lot of space is allocated to the item name, causing the payment dates and customer names to wrap unnecessarily. Is there any way to work around that?

Comment: @Nick The reason for the space allocation is due to the long item name I placed as a test. One way to work around this is to impose a maximum width on the item column, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/2tk4r785

Comment: Although I haven't had a chance to completely test this yet (with some large tables) it definitely seems to be the most workable of the answers; I think I can probably work around the constraint of having to specify a max-width for some columns. Certainly more easily than specifying the width of all columns. Thanks

Comment: Well, I never got the chance to fully test this before as plans changed, but I'm working on a new project now and this - with some minor tweaks to deal with table headings - works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I would suggest the use of flex to achieve your need. Flex is very powerful for this kind of layout as we can easily let the content guide it. Please, see the attached snippet. It is purely made from HTML and CSS. No fixed sizes and no Javascript required.

(old snippet)

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
  /* For demo purposes */
  max-width: 500px; 
  margin: 20px auto; 
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.column {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.inner {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px;
}

.item.heading {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.item:not(.heading) {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

.fixed .narrow {
  flex-basis: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item heading">Customer</div>
    <div class="item">
      <span>Customer Name</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item heading">Items</div>
      <div class="inner fixed">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="item">Item1</div>
          <div class="item narrow">5</div>
          <div class="item last">$400.00</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="item">Item2</div>
          <div class="item narrow">10</div>
          <div class="item last">$200.00</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="item">Item3</div>
          <div class="item narrow">2</div>
          <div class="item last">$500.00</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item heading">Payments</div>
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="item">12 sep 2018</div>
        <div class="item">$3,000.00</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="item">
          18 sep 2018
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          $2,000.00
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**: Changed according to your comment/answer. It somewhat depends on your HTML structure. I had to move the headings to its own "`.row.row-item`" and therefor needed to set a flex-basis to align the columns. This can be extended with multiple "`.row.row-item`". See snippet below.

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
  /* For demo purposes */
  max-width: 600px; 
  margin: 20px auto; 
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.column {
  flex: 1 1 33.33%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.row-item {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.inner {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.item.heading {
  font-weight: bold;
  flex: 1 1 33.33%;
}

.item:not(.heading) {
  flex: 1 1 33.33%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

.fixed .narrow {
  flex: 1 1 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="row row-item">
    <div class="item heading">Customer</div>
    <div class="item heading">Items</div>
    <div class="item heading">Payments</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-item">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="item">
        <span>Customer 1</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="inner fixed">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="item">Item1</div>
            <div class="item narrow">5</div>
            <div class="item last">$400.00</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="item">Item2</div> 
            <div class="item narrow">10</div>
            <div class="item last">$200.00</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="item">Item3</div>
            <div class="item narrow">2</div>
            <div class="item last">$500.00</div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="item">12 sep 2018</div>
          <div class="item">$3,000.00</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="item">
            18 sep 2018
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            $2,000.00
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-item">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="item">
        <span>Customer 304</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="inner fixed">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="item">Item4</div>
            <div class="item narrow">5</div>
            <div class="item last">$6.00</div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="item">20 sep 2018</div>
          <div class="item">$4.00</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="item">
            27 sep 2018
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            $26.00
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-item">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="item">
        <span>Customer 605</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="inner fixed">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="item">Item5</div>
            <div class="item narrow">50</div>
            <div class="item last">$60.00</div>
          </div>          
          <div class="row">
            <div class="item">Item6</div>
            <div class="item narrow">3</div>
            <div class="item last">$260.00</div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="item">29 sep 2018</div>
          <div class="item">$40.00</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="item">
            30 sep 2018
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            $206.00
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks promising. Can you show me how to expand it to multiple rows as in the answer I posted?

Comment: Also see my update to the question. I hope that adds clarity to the problem.

Comment: @Nick updated accordingly. Now supports multiple item rows.

Comment: This is a clever implementation using nested (1-demensional) Flexbox containers. However, when I shrink the browser size or set the viewport to Samsung S9 size (using Firefox DevTools), the columns do not line up properly. Have you considered using 2-dimensional CSS Grid containers?

Comment: @RandyDaddis any chance you could post an answer along those lines so I could evaluate?

Comment: @guitarzero see my answer below. Layouts #1 & #2 need some minor touches. Pull Requests are welcome!!!

Comment: @guitarzero it seems that the only way this maintains alignment is if the column widths are all fixed. Is there any way around that?

Comment: I would use `<table>` for tables.

Answer (score 9):

I was eventually able to solve this by writing an `onload` function to find the maximum height of all the nested tables in a given row and then set the height of every nested table in that row to the same value.

```
window.onload=function () {
    let rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
    for (let r = 0; r < rows.length; r++) {
        let subtables = rows[r].querySelectorAll('.subtable');
        let maxHeight = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < subtables.length; i++) {
            maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, subtables[i].clientHeight);
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < subtables.length; i++) subtables[i].style.height='' + maxHeight + 'px';
    }
};
```

The only downside of this solution was that it meant I had to assign widths to the `<td>`s in the nested tables. However since I could use percentage widths this wasn't too big an issue for me:

```
<table class="display" cellpadding="0">
    <tr><th>Customer</th><th>Items</th><th>Payments</th></tr>
    <tr><td>Customer 1</td>
        <td class="d-subtable"><table class="subtable" cellpadding="0"><tr><td width="35%">Item1</td><td width="20%">5</td><td width="45%">$400.00</td></tr><tr><td>Item2</td><td>10</td><td>$200.00</td></tr><tr><td>Item3</td><td>2</td><td>$500.00</td></tr></table></td>
        <td class="d-subtable"><table class="subtable" cellpadding="0"><tr><td width="60%">12 Sep 2018</td><td width="40%">$3,000.00</td></tr><tr><td>18 Sep 2018</td><td>$2,000.00</td></tr></table></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Customer 2</td>
        <td class="d-subtable"><table class="subtable" cellpadding="0"><tr><td width="35%">Item4</td><td width="20%">5</td><td width="45%">$600.00</td></tr></table></td>
        <td class="d-subtable"><table class="subtable" cellpadding="0"><tr><td width="60%">20 Sep 2018</td><td width="40%">$4,000.00</td></tr><tr><td>27 Sep 2018</td><td>$2,000.00</td></tr></table></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Final output:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This example is a responsive design which utilizes only HTML and nested CSS Grids inside of a Flexbox.

I took the liberty of adding headers and a pagination placeholder to your scenario. These may be removed without affecting the rest of the layout.

I have created a GitHub repo [nested-CSS-Grid-and-Flexbox-Playground](https://github.com/RandyDaddis/nested-CSS-Grid-and-Flexbox-Playground) which contains an Angular application utilizing this layout with dynamic data as well as references I accumulated while researching this project.

## HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Customers List</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="list">
      <div class="customer-column-header">Customers</div>
      <div class="invoice-column-header">Invoices</div>
      <div class="payments-column-header">Payments</div>
      <div class="customer-row">
        <div class="customer-column">
          <div>Acme Widget Manufacturing, Inc.</div>
        </div>
        <ul class="invoice-column">
          <li class="invoice-row-header">
            <div>Description</div>
            <div>Quantity</div>
            <div>Price</div>
          </li>
          <li class="invoice-row">
            <div>Item 1</div>
            <div>5</div>
            <div>$400.00</div>
          </li>
          <li class="invoice-row">
            <div>Item 2</div>
            <div>10</div>
            <div>$200.00</div>
          </li>
          <li class="invoice-row">
            <div>Item 3</div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>$500.00</div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="payment-column">
          <li class="payment-row-header">
            <div>Date</div>
            <div>Amount</div>
          </li>
          <li class="payment-row">
            <div>12 Sep 2018</div>
            <div>$3,000.00</div>
          </li>
          <li class="payment-row">
            <div>18 Sep 2018</div>
            <div>$2,000.00</div>
          </li>
          <li class="payment-row">
            <div>12 Sep 2018</div>
            <div>$3,000.00</div>
          </li>
          <li class="payment-row">
            <div>18 Sep 2018</div>
            <div>$2,000.00</div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="customer-row">
        <div class="customer-column">
          <div>Beta Company</div>
        </div>
        <ul class="invoice-column">
          <li class="invoice-row-header">
            <div>Description</div>
            <div>Quantity</div>
            <div>Price</div>
          </li>
          <li class="invoice-row">
            <div>Item 1</div>
            <div>5</div>
            <div>$400.00</div>
          </li>
          <li class="invoice-row">
            <div>Item 2</div>
            <div>10</div>
            <div>$200.00</div>
          </li>
          <li class="invoice-row">
            <div>Item 3</div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>$500.00</div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="payment-column">
          <li class="payment-row-header">
            <div>Date</div>
            <div>Amount</div>
          </li>
          <li class="payment-row">
            <div>12 Sep 2018</div>
            <div>$3,000.00</div>
          </li>
          <li class="payment-row">
            <div>18 Sep 2018</div>
            <div>$2,000.00</div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pagination">
      <p>Pagination Placeholder</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

## CSS

```
*, *::before, *::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.container {
  width: 62.5rem;
  max-width: 80rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header {
  padding: .5rem;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  align-self: center;
}

.list {
  background-color: darkcyan;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(2, minmax(min-content, 1fr));
}

.customer-column-header {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.invoice-column-header {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}

.payments-column-header {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
}

.customer-column-header,
.invoice-column-header,
.payments-column-header {
  padding: .5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.customer-row {
  border-left: 1px solid;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  background-color: orangered;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(2, minmax(min-content, 1fr));
}

.customer-column {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.invoice-column {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}

.payment-column {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
}

.customer-column {
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: right;
}

  .customer-column > div {
    padding: 1rem;
  }

.invoice-column {
  border-left: 1px solid;
}

.invoice-row-header {
  background-color: darkcyan;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(6rem, 1fr));
  justify-self: stretch;
}

  .invoice-row-header > div {
    text-align: right;
    padding: .5rem;
    justify-self: stretch;
    align-self: stretch;
  }

    .invoice-row-header > div:nth-child(2) {
      border-left: 1px solid;
      border-right: 1px solid;
    }

.invoice-row {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(6rem, 1fr));
  justify-items: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
}

  .invoice-row > div {
    text-align: right;
    padding: .5rem;
    justify-self: stretch;
    align-self: stretch;
  }

  .invoice-row div:nth-child(2) {
    border-left: 1px solid;
    border-right: 1px solid;
  }

.payment-column {
  border-left: 1px solid;
}

.payment-row-header {
  background-color: darkcyan;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(6rem, 1fr));
  justify-self: stretch;
}

  .payment-row-header > div {
    text-align: right;
    padding: .5rem;
    justify-self: stretch;
    align-self: stretch;
  }

    .payment-row-header > div:nth-child(1) {
      border-right: 1px solid;
    }

.payment-row {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(6rem, 1fr));
  justify-items: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
}

  .payment-row > div {
    text-align: right;
    padding: .5rem;
    justify-self: stretch;
    align-self: stretch;
  }

    .payment-row > div:nth-child(1) {
      border-right: 1px solid;
    }

.pagination {
  padding: .5rem;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  align-self: center;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 120rem) {

  .container {
    max-width: 80rem;
    margin: 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 80rem) {

  .container {
    max-width: 62.5rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 62.5rem) {

  .container {
    max-width: 45rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .list {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(autofit, 100%);
  }

  .customer-column-header,
  .invoice-column-header,
  .payments-column-header {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
  }

  .customer-row {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(autofit, 100%);
    justify-content: center;
  }

    .customer-row .customer-column,
    .customer-row .invoice-column,
    .customer-row .payments-column {
      grid-column: 1 / -1;
    }

  .customer-column {
    justify-self: center;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 45rem) {

  .container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

> cref:https://codepen.io/randydaddis/pen/LqEjEg

Comment: Thanks for this - a lot of unfamiliar css properties for me. Time to do some research...

Comment: [Advanced CSS and Sass: Flexbox, Grid, Animations and More](https://www.udemy.com/advanced-css-and-sass/learn/v4/overview) is a 28 hour class with in depth lectures and is worth consideration.

Comment: The latest update looks good - is there any way to get the heights of the subgrids to match?

Comment: I tried modifying your codepen with the revised code but it doesn't seem to have stretched the payments grid...

Comment: Perhaps you were looking an experimental fork. I removed that fork. The invoice & payment cols yellow bg exposed on the column with less rows. The invoice & payment cols stretch to the customer row. The issue is stretching the shorter of invoice or payment row list to its parent column. Theoretically, that should work, but I haven't figured that out yet. If you cut or copy/paste rows within the invoice and payment columns, you should see yellow backgrounds exposed at the bottom of the column with less rows. It appears at the bottom because the column items are aligned to the top of the column.

Comment: I added another customer to the CodePen. Customer 1 has more payment rowss and customer 2 has more invoice rows. The yellow background shows where the invoice or payment column stretches to the customer row.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid the yellow background by stretching the individual invoices/payments rows?

Comment: I have not been able to stretch the individual invoice/payment rows yet. Best solution for now is to remove the background color from the invoice/payment columns and they will inherit the customer row background color.

Answer (score 4):

## No `rowspan`s or `colspan`s Were Harmed Making This Table

The following is a diagram of the table sans thead:

[image: ![enter image description here]

<sup>The term *"column"* is termed loosely. For example: column `td.items` refers to all 
`td.items` as a group.</sup>

1. There is the main table...
2. ...and then a tbody for each customer row. Having multiple tbodies is valid.
3. Next is a tr and then...
4. ...a td. This td is the columns: `.customer`, `.items`, and `.payments`.
5. Within each td is a sub-table and sub-tbody.
6. The first column `td.customer` is limited to one sub-row since the content for each 
   `tbody.row` is just a 
    customer's name. The cells for this column have the properties 
   that control `tbody.row` height 
   (see comments in demo).
7. The second column `td.items` can have multiple sub-rows, the demo features from 1 to 3
   sub-rows.
8. The last column `td.payments` can have multiple sub-rows as well, the demo features
   2 sub-rows each.

---

### Demo

**Details are commented in demo**

- The demo is responsive (might need MQ for edge cases and mobile devices).
- Valid HTML/CSS and semantically sound.
- No JavaScript/jQuery.
- Built purely with `<table>`, `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, `<tr>`, `<th>`, and `<td>` tags (not even a div or span).

```css
* { border: 0px none transparent; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; }

/* 
|- table-layout: fixed; 
|| Gives you more control over table behavior such as setting column widths and 
|| table adhering to them.
===
|- height: 100%; width: 100%; 
|| Applied to table.main as well as the nested tables. It facilitates all of 
|| the nested tables to stretch evenly within tbody.row.
*/
table { border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid #000; 
table-layout: fixed; height: 100%; width: 100%; }

table table { border: 1px solid #000; }

.main { min-height: 40vh; }

th { border-bottom: 2px solid #000; outline: 1px solid #000; }

/*
|| This rule set determines content wrapping behavior within each cell.
*/
td td { border: 1px solid #000; padding: 0px 5px; word-wrap: break-word; 
word-break:break-word; overflow: hidden}

.items td:first-of-type { width: 30%; }

.items td:nth-of-type(2) { width: 25%; text-align: right; }

.items td:last-of-type { width: 45%; text-align: right; }

.payments td:last-of-type { text-align: right; }

.customer,
.items,
.payments { border: 0px none transparent; padding: 0px; }

th:first-of-type { border-left: 3px solid #000; width: 20%; }

th:nth-of-type(2) { width: 40%; }

th:last-of-type { border-right: 3px solid #000; width: 40%; }

/*
|| This allows the tr.row to always be equal in height as well as being
|| responsive. This column was the best choice as the one to stabilize height 
|| since the content probably changes the least and it has the most space to use
|| hidden spacers (see next comment). 
*/
.customer table { min-height: 20vh; } 

/*
|| This sets a &nbsp; within the cells in the first column. Although vh units
|| are very responsive, they will start collapsing if the viewport height is 
|| reduced disproportionately vs. viewport width. Thus, this pseudo-element
|| ensures a minimum height of 60px for both tr.row.
*/
.customer td::after { content: '\a0'; display: inline-block; width:0.5px; 
min-height: 60px; line-height: 60px; vertical-align: middle; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
</head>
<body>

<table class='main'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Customer</th><th>Items</th><th>Payments</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class='row'>
   <tr>
    <td class='customer'>
      <table><tr><td>
      Customer 1
      </td></tr></table>
    </td>
    <td class='items'>
      <table>
        <tr><td>Item1</td><td>5</td><td>$400.00</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Item2</td><td>100</td><td>$20.00</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Item3</td><td>2</td><td>$500.00</td></tr>
     </table>
   </td>
   <td class='payments'>
     <table>
       <tr><td>12 Sep 2018</td><td>$3,000.00</td></tr>
       <tr><td>18 Sep 2018</td><td>$2,000.00</td></tr>
     </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 
 <tbody class='row'>
  <tr>
   <td class='customer'>
    <table><tr><td>
      Customer 304
      </td></tr></table>
   </td>
   <td class='items'>
   <table>
     <tr><td>Item4</td><td>5</td><td>$6.00</td></tr>
   </table>
  </td>
  <td class='payments'>
   <table>
     <tr><td>20 Sep 2018</td><td>$4.00</td></tr>
     <tr><td>27 Sep 2018</td><td>$26.00</td></tr>
   </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>

 <tbody class='row'>
   <tr>
    <td class='customer'>      
     <table><tr><td>
      Customer 888
      </td></tr></table>
    </td>
    <td class='items'>
     <table>
        <tr><td>Item5</td><td>50</td><td>$100.00</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Item6</td><td>10</td><td>$500.00</td></tr>
     </table>
   </td>
   <td class='payments'>
     <table>
       <tr><td>10 Nov 2018</td><td>$3,000.00</td></tr>
       <tr><td>17 Nov 2018</td><td>$7,000.00</td></tr>
     </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

---

#### References

**[`table-layout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout)**

[**`vh`** and **`vw`**](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/)

**[`word-wrap: break-word; word-break:break-word;`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35251345/2813224)**

**[`:first-/:nth-/:last-of-type`](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/)**

**[`::before/after`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I like the fact that you were able to get the same result as I did without resorting to javascript, but it does still suffer from the problem of having to specify column widths, which I was trying to avoid.

Comment: @Nick I can remove the widths bad news: all columns widths are even -- good news: All three rows are still at perfect and equal heights. Updated...it's too symmetrical

Comment: That is weird. I guess `table-layout: fixed` just divides things equally when no widths are specified.

Answer (score 1):

The problem as given can actually be solved rather straightforward with nesting CSS `grid` layouts.

(If there there was `colspan` or `rowspan` that would require using their counterparts `grid-column` and `grid-row`.)

I simplified the HTML so the solution can be understood more clearly - though that loses the semantics of the table.

If it's desired to maintain the table markup then the intervening tags (e.g. the `<tr>`) need to be styled as `display:contents` to ensure they don't break up the layout (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65163660/alignment-of-rows-in-nested-css-grid)).

```css
/* defining the grid */
.grid{display:grid;grid-gap:0 0;}
.grid-2col{grid-template-columns:auto auto;}
.grid-3col{grid-template-columns:auto auto auto;}

/* making it look like a table. */
.th{font-weight:bold;}
.grid>*{
   border:1px solid black;
   padding:5px;}

/* avoiding double borders. */

/* no double top border - first row can be recognized by class .th */
.grid>*{border-top:none;}
.th{border-top:1px solid black;}

/* no double side border - first column can be recognized modulo number of columns of grid. */
.grid>*{border-left:none;}
.grid-2col>*:nth-child(2n+1){border-left:1px solid black;}
.grid-3col>*:nth-child(3n+1){border-left:1px solid black;}
   
/* no padding in nested tables. */
.grid>.grid{border:none;padding:0px;}
.grid>.grid>*{border-left:none;border-top:none;}
```

```html
<div class="grid grid-3col">
   <span class="th">Customer</span>
   <span class="th">Items</span>
   <span class="th">Payments</span>
   <span>Customer Name</span>
   <div class="grid grid-3col">
      <span>Item1</span>
      <span>5</span>
      <span>$400.00</span>
      <span>Item2</span>
      <span>10</span>
      <span>$200.00</span>
      <span>Item3</span>
      <span>2</span>
      <span>$500.00</span>
   </div>
   <div class="grid grid-2col">
     <span>12 Sep 2018</span>
     <span>$3,000.00</span>
     <span>18 Sep 2018</span>
     <span>$2,000.00</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this - due to other commitments I've run out of time to take a look at it today but will get to it tomorrow. It looks really promising.

Comment: Just had a quick look - this has the same issue that Randy's answer had when you add another row (as in the last example in the question), which is that the column widths in the two nested grids don't line up between rows.

Comment: Well, one can fix that by using only one `grid` with `grid-row` instead of nested ones - but then the rows of the different columns would be lined up, too. `table`, `grid` or `float` - either both `row` and `column` are lined up (possibly spanning multiple cells) or neither are - you can't line up one but not the other. So if you want a vertical line going through then you're also going to get a horizontal one.

Comment: So referencing the line "I would prefer the above table to look like this:" in the question, you can get the image directly above, but not the one below that line (unless, of course, you work with fixed/percentage widths).

Comment: Yeah, that was the conclusion I had come to, and the reason I had moved to a JS solution to fix widths and heights post render. It's ugly, but it does work. Thanks for your answer, I appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of the `<table>` tag has changed between current HTML and older HTML. While `<table>` used to server more of a formatting function, in HTML5 it should only be used for a literal table. As others have mentioned, your setup doesn't really look like a table in the literal sense. So while using a bunch of nested `<table>` elements could accomplish what you want, it's probably not the most effective way.

You could accomplish this by just nesting a bunch of `<div>` elements along with some basic CSS. Here's an example:

```
<div style="width: 1000px; height: 600px; border: 1px solid #000;">
  <div style="width: 100px; height: 600px; display: inline-block; border: 1px solid #000; margin: 0; padding: 0;">X</div>
  <div style="width: 100px; height: 300px; display: inline-block; border: 1px solid #000; margin: 0; padding: 0;">Y</div>
  <div style="width: 100px; height: 300px; display: inline-block; border: 1px solid #000; position: relative; top: 300px; margin: 0; padding: 0; left: -105px;">Z</div>
</div>
```

This will produce the X, Y, and Z parts of the display you describe above. The same technique can be expanded to build the rest of your display.

A few things to note:

- This example uses PXs to determine width, which is **really bad practice** form a CSS perspective. It would be too big on mobile and too small on a large desktop. You could, however, adapt this technique to use a more adaptive format. This will add complexity to the solution though, hence why I chose to use PXs for the example.
- This example uses inline CSS since it's the easiest way to show the solution. However, **this is really bad practice, DON'T ACTUALLY DO THIS**!

Hope this helps.

Comment: See my edit, I have tried to improve the example and explain why I want to use a table. It seems using `<div>`s will make it difficult to have the columns sizes vary with the enclosed data?

Answer (score 0):

Online spreadsheet programs like Google Sheets make it look so easy, but when I first dove in, it was much more complicated. I gave each row a special attribute like row="r_1" and each subrow specific attributes like row="r_1" subrow="sr_1_a".  onkeyup events or an onload triggered math to find all parent rows using querySelectorAll, then made sure their height was equal to all the subrow heights added up.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion I assume that it'd be hard to achieve what you want.

Reasons: `td` are nested in `tr`, so any change in height will affect height of of the associated row.

Suggestion: you can have five separate tabs or divs and have them displayed inline-block, then put your data in them.

If you use this suggestion, please first set a div that wraps the 5 columns and give it a font-size of 0px, then remember to change the font-size to something useful for the children.