# What's up with the style "word-break: break-word"?

Tags: css

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15137272/1525840) as well as [this blog](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/word-break/#article-header-id-0), there's mentioning of the style *word-break* with its values. Also, there's the value *break-word* as something belonging to e.g. *word-wrap* class.

In the recent template for MVC in VS, I found the combination *word-break: break-word* (well, Resharper found it, really). And now I'm curious if it's a valid combo to begin with (which I failed to find when gooling) or if it's an invalid CSS syntax (in which case I wonder why MS put it there and what's the story behind it).

Comment: When I google it, I get https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

Comment: @MrLister Interesting. You got more than I did. However, if you click on the different options at that link, you'll notice that the last option (the one in question here) doesn't do any difference compared to *normal*. Is it something specific to FF? I get the error message on my CSS in CS. Hence, me asking.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35251345/2813224

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are other questions about this subject, for instance [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1795109/1016716) with many excellent answers, but that amount of info may distract from the basic question, *what do the different values to `word-break` do*. So here's an answer to that question and that question only.

If you take this snippet

```css
body {
  max-width: 15em;
  box-shadow: green 0 0 8px;
  word-break: normal;
}
```

```html
Some short words, somewhatlongerwords and extremelylongwordsthatarereallylong for testing purposes.
```

With the default value of `normal`, words are not broken; ordinary word wrap is used and the longest word overflows out of the box. Screenshot:

[image]

---

`break-all` breaks all words at the end of the line, no matter if they would fit in their entirety on the next line or not.

[image]

---

`keep-all` is meant for CJK (Chinese, Japanese and Korean) words, which ordinarily don't have spaces between them.
With pure English text, there's no difference to `normal`.

[image]

<sub>(If you're interested, [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) features an example with Japanese text, where you can see the difference.)</sub>

---

And `break-word` breaks up those words that don't fit in the box. This is not the same as `break-all`, which breaks all words regardless.

[image]

Now this last one is non-standard, and it doesn't work in all browsers, so if you want this, you should also write `overflow-wrap: break-word;` in your stylesheet, and for compatibility with older browsers `word-wrap: break-word;` as well.

There is more to it, but I'll refer you to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1795109/1016716) for the reasoning, the history, etc.

Comment: A bit annoying and surprising that the default template from MS that works on MS browser will flag that syntax as error when using the default IDE from MS. I'm not happy about that. +1 for an awesome answer, though. I'm very happy about it.

Answer (score -1):

Word break - breaks the word to the next line if it exceeds the width.
You can check the css works in the browser or not in the below site.

[caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=word-break)