# Letter Wrapping with CSS

Tags: css

I am using an editor on my page and the word wrapping works fine if they are actually words. Meaning there is a space after  every few characters.

However, if I put my finger on a letter and keep pressing, then the editor will expand beyond the edge of the display.

So I believe the following does the word wrapping showing an scrollbar if necessary:

```
<div style="overflow:scroll;">
```

But that won't work for the above scenario. Do I need a different attribute?
What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: HTML has nothing to do with this. It's all about CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the `word-wrap` attribute, specifically `break-word`, which allows a long word to be broken into sections to allow for wrapping. Try the following:

```css
    div {
      overflow-wrap: break-word; // standard
      word-wrap: break-word; // older, but still needed in IE
    }
```

```html
<div>
ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
</div>
```

You may also find some helpful information in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795109/what-is-the-difference-between-word-break-break-all-versus-word-wrap-break) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54606556/whats-up-with-the-style-word-break-break-word).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. That didn't work but it lead me to the following:     -ms-word-break: break-all;
    word-break: break-all;
    word-break: break-word; which works. Does this have any side effects?

Comment: @Stackedup Not so much "side effects" as just different levels of support in different browsers. That's why you need the different declarations. `break-all` can be dangerous as it basically just breaks wherever it wants, sometimes not-so-intuitively.

Comment: @Stackedup check the answer for some further reading on the matter.